# How to inner join a derived table with Hibernate/NHibernate?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, hql, criteria

*(First i'd like to apologize if this is a duplicate, I can't find any good solution for it even though it must be simple)*

I'm creating reports from sales-data and need to output some aggregated values along with some non-aggregated/non-grouped ones, like Name.

**This is what I'd like to output:**

Total profit per employee with User.Name and SUM(Order.Profit) like this:

> ```
> Name         Profit [+ more aggregated columns]
> -------------------
> John Doe    | $250
> James Smith | $130
> ```

This is fairly simple with plain SQL like:

```
SELECT 
u.Name,
x.TotalProfit
FROM dbo.Users u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  o.UserID as UserID, 
    SUM(o.Profit) AS TotalProfit,
    --[..] more aggregated columns
    FROM Orders o
    GROUP BY o.UserID
) x  ON u.ID = x.ProfitToID
```

I don't want to group by u.Name since it will affect performance (Read more about why at [sqlteam.com](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2005/12/14/8546.aspx))

**How do I do this with NHibernate?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Hibernate` you define the join paths in the mappings. So classes not related in `Java` with another classes cannot join themselves. Hibernate is an ORM  it make sense.

Try creating a `SQLquery`. Works pretty much in the same way that ordinary HQL queries.

Then you would retrieve an array with the data. Parse it or create a DTO with a constructor that fit.

```
select a.b.MyDTO(u.Name, x.TotalProfit) from...

class MyDTO{
    String name;
    int totalProfit;
    public MyDTO(String name, int totalProfit) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Udo.

Comment: You're right, it's an ORM. It would just make it a lot easier if I could use the existing mappings as a base instead of re-inventing them in plain SQL..

Comment: I did not mean to be rude, but my english is not very good. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using fancy SQL like that, just use a native query:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("your query here", SomeDTOClass.class);
```